# Saving techniques at android text game

Tags: java, android, save, sharedpreferences, game-physics

Hello guys I'm making a text game for my Android programming class.

I want to make a survival game.

So I will make this game to Character class, with this character class.

This is survival game, so If player press the next day button, I want to save

the datas.

I think I can solve this problem with save my data with fileIO to make a txt

file.

Then when the application starts, I read this txt file to load the player's data.

But I think there is a problem with this case.

I think that users can modify this data manually. But I don't want this situation.

So How can I solve this problem?

Also, I didn't do this way yet. I need to change way to save my game's data?

I googled it and Found 2 ways to save.

1. Shared preferences
2. Sqlite
3. Txt file saving

What way is better?

If I can save with txt file saving, please tell me how to protect data from modifying manually.

Please answer with this problem!

====================================================================

Sorry for cant using fluent English.. because i'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Several options to do so:

1. Implement a database and secure it using SQLCipher. I never tried it before, but you can give a shot by using [this](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/)
2. Use secure SharedPreference instead of android-stock SharedPreferences. You can find usage of secure SharedPreferences [here](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences). As the example shown:

This is how normal SharedPreferences are saved

```
<map>
     <int name="timeout" value="500" />
     <boolean name="is_logged_in" value="true" />
</map>
```

This is how secure SharedPreferecens are saved:

```
<map>
    <string name="TuwbBU0IrAyL9znGBJ87uEi7pW0FwYwX8SZiiKnD2VZ7">
        pD2UhS2K2MNjWm8KzpFrag==:MWm7NgaEhvaxAvA9wASUl0HUHCVBWkn3c2T1WoSAE/g=rroijgeWEGRDFSS/hg
    </string>
    <string name="8lqCQqn73Uo84Rj">k73tlfVNYsPshll19ztma7U">
        pD2UhS2K2MNjWm8KzpFrag==:MWm7NgaEhvaxAvA9wASUl0HUHCVBWkn3c2T1WoSAE/g=:jWm8KzUl0HUHCVBWkn3c2T1WoSAE/g=
    </string>
</map>
```

Comment: You may look at the example I edited. It is claimed not bullet-proof, but it is already hard to decode the string. @InhoLee

Answer (score 0):

What about encoding the data so that it is human-unreadable?

I guess you currently just have file streams writing the player's data (health, hunger or whatever) directly to a file. The file might look like this:

```
100 50 78 89 6
```

Then you read each number back and assign them to the `Character` object.

And you are afraid that the user might be able to figure which value corresponds to which field and edit the file to cheat. Am I right?

What you can try is to use an `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` to serialise the `Character` object to binary. When the object is in binary, the user would not be able to read it. Also, change the file extension to `.dat` or something like that.

Another way to make it human-undreadable is to base64 encode it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use SQlite** - if your Game is dependent on Device then you may create `SQlite` `DataBase` ,it is best approach to handle Game Data and user information and state of game .

**Use API** - if you do not want to depends on only on Device and if user switch its phone then his Game state is sync from last state , then you must create Data Base on server , `MySql` or `Oracle` and create and use `APIS` in Android.

Answer (score 0):

1.if you need the data of a user  after uninstall app and again install then you should use text file option and you can  hide the file by use the dot(.fileName) it will gonna be hide. 
2.otherwise,if you want to store large data then use sqlite and use tables to store the data
3.For just to store small data use sharedpreference and declare allowBackup =true in manifest in application tag